# Access instance of class in TestNG run in groovy

Tags: spring, groovy, testng

I have a spring-based groovy application that is used as a "framework" for running TestNG tests.

Here is a part of my application

```
@RestController
class Framework{
  def instance

  @RequestMapping("/test/{name}")
  @ResponseBody
  String home(@PathVariable String name) {
    def sourceFile = new File("./tests/${name}/test.groovy")
    groovyClass = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile)
    instance = groovyClass.newInstance()

    def testNG = new TestNG()
    testNG.setOutputDirectory("./results/${name}")
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite()
    suite.setName(name)

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite)
    test.setXmlClasses([new XmlClass(groovyClass)])
    testNG.setXmlSuites([suite])
    testNG.run()

    def resultFile = new File("./results/${name}/emailable-report.html")
    return resultFile.text
  }

  @RequestMapping("/status")
  public String getStatus(){
      return instance.currentMethod

  }
}
```

My example test file looks like

```
class T1{
  public String currentMethod

  @Test
  public void test() {
    //execution
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(){
    //execution
    throw new Exception()
  }
}
```

It works fine as it is but I wanted to implement some additional information to be able to check which method is currently running by adding some more code

```
@BeforeMethod
void setMethodName(){
    String className = this.class.getName()
    def classData = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().toList().reverse().find{ it =~ /${className}/}
    currentMethod = classData.getMethodName()
}
```

However I am not able to access the instance as

```
    instance = groovyClass.newInstance()
```

creates one instance and

```
    testNG.run()
```

creates another which can be confirmed by printing some mesages in construcor.

```
ctor
ctor
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite


===============================================
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Any idea how can I access istance created by TestNG or how to pass existing instance into TestNG runner?
Each time i try to access localhost:8080/status it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

`ITestListener` is what you are looking for. Check [its documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging).

You'll be able to add the listener with:

```
testNG.addListener(....);
```

And we can imagine your listener will have:

```
listener.getCurrentMethod();
```

And fyi, it is possible to [inject a `Method` instance into a `@BeforeMethod` method](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection).